# ROR ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to run rails application. I have installed rails 3 on my computer.. When trying to run it using rails server command, it is asking me to type "bundle install" in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Webyana Tech\Desktop\Rails3\wy_editor>bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/

Fetching source index for http://gems.github.com/

Using rake (0.8.7)

Using ZenTest (4.5.0)

Using RubyInline (3.8.6)

Using abstract (1.0.0)

Using activesupport (3.0.0)

Using builder (2.1.2)

Using i18n (0.4.2)

Using activemodel (3.0.0)

Using erubis (2.6.6)

Using rack (1.2.2)

Using rack-mount (0.6.13)

Using rack-test (0.5.7)

Using tzinfo (0.3.25)

Using actionpack (3.0.0)

Using mime-types (1.16)

Using polyglot (0.3.1)

Using treetop (1.4.9)

Using mail (2.2.15)

Using actionmailer (3.0.0)

Using arel (1.0.1)

Using activerecord (3.0.0)

Using activeresource (3.0.0)

Using addressable (2.2.4)

Using crack (0.1.8)

Installing eventmachine (0.12.10) with native extensions C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_r
uby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:529:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': 
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)


        C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no

checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes

checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no

checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no

checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no

checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes

checking for rb_time_new()... yes

checking for windows.h... yes

checking for winsock.h... yes

checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes

checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes

checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes

checking for main() in -lssl... no

creating Makefile

make
g++ -I. -IC:/Ruby/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby/include/ruby-1.9.1/r
uby/backward -I/C/Ruby/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_
BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_W
IN32 -DHAVE_WINDOWS_H -DHAVE_WINSOCK_H -DWITHOUT_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR    -O3 -g
-Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -
Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o binder.o -c binder.cpp
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
```

Please help me.. I tried googling for this.. But couldnt find anything which is same as above... I guess the eventmachine is failing to install...

Comment: You are missing some sort of dependency. I am not a Windows user myself...so, I'm not really sure what is missing.

Comment: Is it because the eventmachine is not installed properly ?

Comment: why not install it in a ubuntu vm?

Comment: It is trying to build/install eventmachine and is failing. The building docs say `OpenSSL` and `libstd++` may be required. I'd look into installing dependencies like this in Windows. Link: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/Building-EventMachine

Comment: So what should be done next...

Comment: Do i need to install VC6 for the eventmachine to build native extension properly?? I tried to install the event machine and it showed 1 gem installed..

Comment: Or g++ package manager.. If so, how do I do that.. Please help me as I am newbie in ROR

Comment: Like I said, not really familiar with Windows dev setup. Hoping someone chimes in

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm having the exact error messages as yours when doing a "bundle install". For now you'll have to install an older version of "eventmachine", separately. Type "gem install eventmachine -v 0.12.8". It installed successfully for me.</strike>

@user662539: Well, I did have "*eventmachine (0.12.8)*" installed successfully, but I'm still couldn't start thin server. I got a error message prompting *"This application has failed to start because msvcrt-ruby18.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem."*. Even if I copied over "*msvcrt-ruby18.dll*" from "*\Ruby187\bin*" to "*\Ruby192\bin*", I got another error message regarding "*Segmentation fault*".

So I revert my ruby version back to *ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]* and able to start thin server.

Sorry I'm not able to help you on this one, but these my new findings.

Comment: I tried installing older version of eventmachine using the command above.. But got the same error while trying to bundle install.. I am using windows 7 and ruby 1.9.2 with rails 3

Comment: Finally i could install  eventmachine (1.0.0.beta.2) in runy 1.9.2 with rails 3.. and all the bundles were installed properly... But when I try